# Visualizing optical dense flows

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, video

I am doing an optical dense flow with the Farenback method provided in opencv (and testing others) over a 300x300 video frames. Currently, I am visualizing the optical flow with the method proposed by the tutorial on the original page of OpenCV, source code, at the bottom, [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html). The result image is similar too. The problem is that the colors blink too fast for me to check if they are providing about-accurate measures of the displacement vectors.
Is it possible, instead of that color-base representation, I to achieve the one in the image below? (I don't need every pixel to be mapped).
What algorithms should I look for? What is the name of that method, as I saw 'displacement field' and 'motion field' but opencv did not return any related methods?

[image: The image is taken from a Youtube video.]

Comment: `flow` has the magnitude and angle for every pixel, right? So just iterate over X and Y with some fixed stride, and at each position draw an arrow of appropriate size and direction -- [`cv::arrowedLine`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga0a165a3ca093fd488ac709fdf10c05b2) might be of help.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you! Would you recommend me anything for the second question? About the DIS optical flow? If you want, I will upload a gif or an image at least to see how it looks like. Again, thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest you post that second part as a separate question, and keep this one solely focused on the visualization. Providing some example images to illustrate the issue is a good idea. | BTW, in here, are you interested in a Python solution? Maybe add a language tag...